# Export Yolov5 to Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

A have some issues exporting yolov5 model to tensor flow. I'm new to tensorflow and yolov5 so following the docs got me in to troubles. What is the easiest way to export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yolov5 supports export to two TF formats: TensorFlow SavedModel and TensorFlow GraphDef. For exporting to both:

```
python export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --include saved_model pb
```

For inference

```
python detect.py --weights yolov5s_saved_model
```

and

```
python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pb
```

respectively

Comment: Inference is the part that confused me, What is an inference?

Comment: Try it out yourself and you will see what the result is :)

Comment: `python detect.py --weights yolov5s_saved_model` uses coco 128 weights.